# In JSON Object parent key name remove and Include its inner content

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is my JSON Object in this i want to remove "item" key from json and want to keep its inner object include with "children" and its tree like JOSN. How can I do this?

```
[
    {
      "item": {
        "id": 11865,
        "parentid": null,
        "levelid": 63,
        "name": "Total"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "item": {
            "id": 10143,
            "parentid": 11865,
            "levelid": 19,
            "name": "Productive"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You should show your expected output.

Comment: Sorry for that, I explain this in new thread [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958657/how-to-create-json-like-a-tree-structure-using-id-and-parentid-from-other-json-o

Answer (score 0):

try

```
objArray = objArray.map( function(value){ 
   var item = value.item; 
   for( var key in item ) 
   { 
     value[key] = item[key]; 
   } 
   delete value.item; 
   return value;
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/09prkkn6/)

**Explanation**

1)   Use `map` to iterate on each item (`value`) of this given array `objArray`.

2)   Get the `item` property of `value`, assign them to `value` directly

3)   Finally delete the `item` property of the `value`.

**Faster option**

```
objArray = objArray.map( function(value){ 
   var item = value.item; 
   var itemKeys = Object.keys(item); 
   for( var counter = 0; counter < itemKeys.length; counter++ ) 
   { 
     value[itemKeys[counter]] = item[itemKeys[counter]]; 
   } 
   delete value.item; 
   return value;
});
```

Comment: will for-in query properties in the parent prototype ? Object.keys() better off from an efficiency stand point ?

Comment: @82Tuskers Not sure I see a huge benefit in this case since number of properties are quite small. Will update the answer with another options anyways since `.keys` seems to be faster http://jsperf.com/object-keys-foreach-vs-for-in-hasownproperty/8

Comment: yeah .. the problem is not so much in the user object but the host object. The user object will have that in its prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want your object to look like after correctly, then this should do the trick:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
    {
      "item": {
        "id": 11865,
        "parentid": null,
        "levelid": 63,
        "name": "Total"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "item": {
            "id": 10143,
            "parentid": 11865,
            "levelid": 19,
            "name": "Productive"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
]
arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.id = obj.item.id;
  obj.parentid = obj.item.parentid;
  obj.levelid = obj.item.levelid;
  obj.name = obj.item.name;
  delete obj.item;
});
```

All this is doing is manually moving the data from `obj.item` to `obj` and then deleting `obj.item` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursion, which keeps the content of `item` and adds the children property as well.

```js
function delItem(a, i, aa) {
    var children = a.children;
    if (a.item) {
        aa[i] = a.item;
        aa[i].children = children;
        delete a.item;
    }
    Array.isArray(children) && children.forEach(delItem);
}

var array = [{ "item": { "id": 11865, "parentid": null, "levelid": 63, "name": "Total" }, "children": [{ "item": { "id": 10143, "parentid": 11865, "levelid": 19, "name": "Productive" } }] }];
array.forEach(delItem);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
//your original array of objects
var array = [{
  "item": {
    "id": 11865,
    "parentid": null,
    "levelid": 63,
    "name": "Total"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "item": {
        "id": 10143,
        "parentid": 11865,
        "levelid": 19,
        "name": "Productive"
      }
    }
  ]
}, ...];

array.forEach(function(parent) {
    flattenKey(parent, 'item');
});

function flattenKey(parent, keyName) {
    var section = parent[keyName];
    var child = section ? section : {};
    var keys = Object.keys(child);
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        parent[key] = child[key];
    })
    delete parent[keyName];
}
```

basically, the function **flattenKey** would flatten any key for a given object (given its key).

1. logic is similar to other solutions here: iterate through child keys and assign their values to the parent object (flattening).
2. then it deletes the child key after step 1.