# How to create json like a tree structure using id and parentid from other json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have a json like:

```
[{
            "id": 11865,
            "parentid": null,
            "levelid": 63,
            "name": "Total"
        },
        {
            "id": 10143,
            "parentid": 11865,
            "levelid": 19,
            "name": "Productive"
        },
        {
            "id": 11873,
            "parentid": 10143,
            "levelid": 20,
            "name": "Regular"
        },
        {
            "id": -852,
            "parentid": 11873,
            "levelid": 255,
            "name": "801-REGULAR"
        },
        {
            "id": -888,
            "parentid": 11873,
            "levelid": 255,
            "name": "888-Regular 2"
        }]
```

And I need to change it some thing like that

```
[{
  "id":11865,
  "levelid":63,
  "parentid": null,
  "name": "Total",
  "children":[{ 
                "id":10143, 
                "parentid":11865, 
                "level":19, 
                "name": "Productive"
                "children":[{
                              "id": 10144,
                              "parentid":10143,
                              "levelid":20,
                              "name": "Other",
                              "children":[{......}]
             }];
```

This new json is based on parent child relation. Also I am implementing this on sever side in node js. Can Any one help on this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert parent-child array to tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792794/convert-parent-child-array-to-tree)

Comment: Ya look a like I will try that. thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proposal which creates a tree and takes a given `parentid` as a root for the tree. This solution works for unsorted data.

> How it works:
>
> Basically for every object in the array it takes as well the `id` for building a new object as the `parentid` for a new object.
>
> So for example
>
> ```
> { "id": 6, "parentid": 4 }
> ```
>
> it generates first with `id` this property
>
> ```
> "6": {
>     "id": 6,
>     "parentid": 4
> }
> ```
>
> and then this property with `parentid`
>
> ```
> "4": {
>     "children": [
>         {
>             "id": 6,
>             "parentid": 4
>         }
>     ]
> },
> ```
>
> and while all object treated like this, we finally get a tree.
>
> If `parentid === root` the root node is found. This is the object for the later return.

```js
var data = [{ "id": 11865, "parentid": null, "levelid": 63, "name": "Total" }, { "id": 10143, "parentid": 11865, "levelid": 19, "name": "Productive" }, { "id": 11873, "parentid": 10143, "levelid": 20, "name": "Regular" }, { "id": -852, "parentid": 11873, "levelid": 255, "name": "801-REGULAR" }, { "id": -888, "parentid": 11873, "levelid": 255, "name": "888-Regular 2" }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r, o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            a.children = o[a.id] && o[a.id].children;
            o[a.id] = a;
            if (a.parentid === root) {
                r = a;
            } else {
                o[a.parentid] = o[a.parentid] || {};
                o[a.parentid].children = o[a.parentid].children || [];
                o[a.parentid].children.push(a);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, null);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(tree, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```